# Why XSD spec accepts timezones having -14H?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, timezone, xquery

I was playing around with some dateTime functions in xquery, and I've noticed that xquery accepts dates with timezones having -14 hours.

Looking at wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets) I can see the minimum allowed timezone is -12H, but the [xpath functions](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#component-extraction-functions) seem to allow -14H. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Timezones Around the World

While +/-12h (with other words: a day) would be sufficient to span the whole world, there are reasons to deviate further. A great example are Tonga and Samoa with +13h, actually being *west of* Howland and Baker Island having -12h. This makes sense: Howland and Baker Island are attached to the US (having -8h at the west shore), while for Tonga and Samoa trade with Australia and New Zealand is much more important. Kiribati and the Line Islands even have +14h by default.

### Timezones Change

Timezones change from time to time. Especially around the date border, it happens that states decide trade and cooperation with another country "on the other side" of the date zone is more important and adjust their own time zone for easier communication.  [Samoa actually changed their timezone just recently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samoa#21st_century).

Allowing +/-14h provides *some* flexibility considering political changes without requiring changes to the specifications. +14h seems a little bit arbitrary, though; let's hope French Polynesia (or any of the other small islands related more closely to Europe than America don't consider changing their time zone to +15h.

Comment: Well, I had to read your answer twice and look at the map 1-2 more to understand it better, but now It makes sense. So the spec is just giving a small extra room of 2 hours in the lower and upper theoretical limit of 12 hours, but that's about it. To be honest It looks to me like they are asking for trouble, having the same upper limit as the current maximum time zone offset.

Comment: Also, shouldn't a dateTime having an offset of -13 or -14 considered invalid, from a business point of view, since it is not used anywhere?

Comment: There is a tendency for politicians to put the clock forward in order to persuade people to get out of bed earlier, which helps the economy; so it's much more likely that someone will move to +15 than that anyone will adopt -14. But the standard had to put a boundary somewhere.

Comment: Michael while I understand the political reasons to change the offset of a country, I don't actually understand the technical reasons to keep the boundary so close to the actual values. By standard, do you mean the XML spec? Because I can't find any other reference to why this number is so small. (+- 14)

Answer (score 2):

It comes from ISO, which goes to 14 in both directions. Although there are no areas that currently define their time as -14 there are some that define it as +14 (Tonga) and Etc/GMT-14 is a -14:00 offset.

Comment: I can't understand why this answer is upvoted. Can you please explain? I can't find any reference of this in the ISO 8601, or in any RFC. I can only find [RFC 2822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt), which states: 

and the **zone MUST be within the range -9959 through +9959.**

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.  XSD 1.0 says in [one place](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime)

> All timezoned times are Coordinated Universal Time (UTC, sometimes called "Greenwich Mean Time"). Other timezones indicated in lexical representations are converted to UTC during conversion of literals to values. "Local" or untimezoned times are presumed to be the time in the timezone of some unspecified locality as prescribed by the appropriate legal authority; currently there are no legally prescribed timezones which are durations whose magnitude is greater than 14 hours.

In [another](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime-order), it says:

> Based on timezones currently in use, [the value 2000-01-20T12:00:00Z] could vary from 2000-01-20T12:00:00+12:00 to 2000-01-20T12:00:00-13:00. It is, however, possible for this range to expand or contract in the future, based on local laws. Because of this, the following definition uses a somewhat broader range of indeterminate values: +14:00..-14:00.

This suggests to me that Jens Erat's suggestion (allow offsets a little greater than any currently known to be needed, just in case) hits the mark pretty well.  I have not consulted the discussion lists of the XSD WG for the relevant period to see whether other arguments were brought forward.

As for the possibility that some jurisdiction or other shifts to an offset of +15:00, JE is right that that could be a bit awkward.  The issue may have seemed less important in XSD 1.0, since in 1.0 the time zone offset was only a lexical phenomenon and had nothing to do with the value (which was always UTC); it may seem more important in 1.1 (and in XPath 2.0 and related specs), where the time zone offset *is* part of the value.

But one of the big motivators for such offset shifts seemed (at the time, at least to some in the WG) to be the desire to be the part of the world where the second millennium would arrive first, with the attendant hope of extra tourism revenue. That motive, at least, has faded for the moment.

And in any case, even if the time zone offset is part of the value, its relation to local civil time is almost never going to be simple.  Many jurisdictions change the offset of local civil time to UTC in unpredictable ways (and not just in the search for tourism revenue).  Anyone who wants to relate a time value to local civil time must use something other than a naked `time` value, with or without offset.  (Is 10:00:00.00-05:00 saying this happens at 10 Eastern [Standard] Time? or 10 Central [Daylight] Time?  Is a time marked 10 a.m. Eastern Time before, or after, time 14:30:00.0Z?  In the general case, the only possible answer is "yes, probably".)

As with leap seconds, so also with time zone offsets:  it would be nice to have a datatype that accepts all legitimate values, rejects all bogus values, and is computationally and organizationally tractable.  And since we don't seem to be able to define such a type, we make the best approximation we can manage, and move on.  (And why is the solution in one case to allow values which seem to be bogus, like an offset that no jurisdiction actually uses, and in the other case to disallow values which are in fact legitimate, like those that fall within leap seconds? Good question.  The only answer I can offer is:  The WG made the best approximation it could manage, and ... eventually ... moved on.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and for considering my question valuable. So this has nothing to do with the ISO, it was just a decision from the past that just hasn't created problems yet, correct? I still don't understand why the XML spec didn't go with the RFC 2822 suggestion of +9999 -9999 zone offset. I have to guess the RFC was not available when the XML spec was defined.

Comment: I can't refute it, but I think the conclusion "this has nothing to do with ... ISO" goes a bit beyond the evidence currently available.  No connection to an ISO spec has been exhibited; that's suggestive, but not conclusive.

Comment: W.r.t. allowing 99 hours and 99 minutes of offset from UTC, the idea never arose: the WG started from ISO 8601, not RFC 2822 or its predecessor(s).  ISO 8601 defines time zone offsets as a way of indicating the difference between local time and UTC; XSD chose a range that covered known and easily foreseeable local offsets.  If any jurisdiction ever establishes a local time four days and three hours ahead of UTC, then the authors of RFC 822 and 2822 will have been remarkably prescient; until then, an offset of 99 hours is just bogus.  OK for a mail format, perhaps; not much use for validation.

Comment: It seems I was just confused about the relationship of XML with ISO and IETF standards. This explanation clear things up more. Thanks again.